# How to position a div element only after having scrolled horizontally?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I'm looking for a way to position the #header element of my page as "fixed" only after having scrolled for around 100% to the right.

If left < 100% Then

```
#header { display:none; }
```

If Left > 100% Then

```
#header { position:fixed, top:0, left:0, width:50px, height:50px, color:red, z-index:9999; }
```

I tried this :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var header = $("#header");
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollLeft() > 1920) {
        header.css({"position" : "fixed", "top" : "0", "left" : "0", "width" : "50px", "height" : "50px", "background" : "red", "z-index" : "9999"});
    } else {
        header.css({"display" : "none"});
}
});
</script>
```

But it doesn't work. And is it possible to make a condition with a percentage instead of an amount of pixels ? (100% instead of 1920)

Could you help me, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing 1920 with "window.innerWidth". Thats a JS DOM variable for the width of the browser window.

Comment: Thank you for this part of my request ! But I think there's a mistake somewhere else, it doesn't work...

Comment: could you make an example in a JSFiddle or similar so we could have a complete reference?

Comment: otherwise there is little way for someone to help- and honesty this other problem is better posed in a new question.

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mzh8an8g/1/
My first problem is to display the element #header. As I'm not able to do it for the moment, I can't test your "window.innerWidth" tip...

Comment: Try my changes here: http://jsfiddle.net/3zrw2xko/

The big problem was that you weren't removing display:none in the alternate case.

Comment: Thank you ! It's working in the JSFiddle demo, but unfortunately not on my  real project and I don't understand why. I will investigate, anyway...

Comment: Glad to see it working to a degree. If you're satisfied with my help please accept this answer by clicking the checkmark next to my original answer and ask a new question if you require more help when you figure out why it doesn't work in your environment.

Comment: OK, I found the mistake : I had to add this just before the JS script 
`//<![CDATA[ $(window).load(function(){"`
and this `});//]]>` at the end